# Encoding my string to send an http request via C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, url-encoding

I am trying to send a simple HTTP request like this:

```
var client = new WebClient();                
string myString="this is the string i want to send";
message = client.DownloadString("http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.xml?text=" + myString + "&api_key="+currentKey);
```

but some of the strings I send includes # or & or such characters, so I want to encode the string first before sending it, because it throws an error if it includes these special characters without being encoded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx).
Unlike `HttpUtility`, this works on the client profile too.

Answer (score 5):

Use **[HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)**